# How could I solve this PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, heat-equation, graph-laplacian

Can anybody please let me know an idea about solving the following PDE for a given initial condition $T_0=0$ and boundary conditions $T(0,w)=u_0$?

\begin{equation*}
  \nabla_w T_t(t,w) + T(t,w) . \nabla_w L_w + L_w . \nabla_w T(t,w) = 0
\end{equation*}
where $L_w = \sum_{i,j} w_{i,j} x_{i,j}$ and $x \in \{0,1\}$ and $0 \leq w\leq 1$.

The above formula is gradient of heat equation on a edge-weighted graph. $x_{ij}$ are present if the edge is in graph. $w$ is the edge-weight of graph. and finally, $L_w$ is the weighted Laplacian of the graph

Comment: $x$ and $w$ are both matrices? the indices denote the derivative w.r.t. the corresponding variable? Does the lower dot denote a scalar product? From where to where does $T$ map?

Comment: If $x\in \{0,1\}$ what is $x_{i,j}$ then? What is the relation to the heat equation?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1, I added some explanations

Comment: So briefly saying: "Is this a discrete pde"? Unfortunately, I don't know how the differential operators are defined on graphs.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1, I would say no. Since we have relaxed weights to be chosen from an interval instead of having binary weights!